# How to test a script using a different browster navigation language

Tags: javascript, testing, navigator

I'm working on a script to adapt my website to the user's default language.

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

But when I change the browser language in Chrome or IE, there's no difference (even after deleting the cache and restarting the program). It keeps coming back as "en-US".

**How do you change the navigation language (or is there a website to simulate that)?**